# Windows 8 challenge - participation for a post before the challenge started

Tags: support, windows-8-challenge

I [answered](https://superuser.com/questions/434776/how-do-i-search-the-windows-8-store/434778#434778) a question regarding searching the Windows Store in Windows 8 before the Windows 8 challenge started. This post would qualify me for Level 2 in the challenge, as it's got a score of 6.

Since it was posted before the challenge started, will I receive participation credit or no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was posted before the challenged started, so no that doesn't get counted.

(For citation, check Darth Android's [query](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/118?m=6579456#6579456) where he [posted half hour](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/118?m=6580149#6580149) before it started, but isn't considered)

Comment: @tapped-out Though some may consider this to be harsh, this is done on purpose to give everyone an equal chance... otherwise [I would've already won](http://superuser.com/search?q=%5Bwindows-8%5D+user%3A47225) :P and [many others](http://superuser.com/tags/windows-8/topusers) would've been ahead right away